# Colored medical manhwa/manhua where the ghost of the youngest genius surgeon follows a lazy resident

Tags: story-identification, manga, ghost, medicine

I need help finding a manhua/manhua where the main character (MC), who has typical brown/dark-hair and brown eyes, is really lazy and barely studies and doesn't get good grades either. But one day, there's a news article about the death of the youngest genius doctor in a car crash. The genius doctor had white hair; I cant remember the eye color. And so one day, when the MC was out taking a walk, he sees the genius doctor sleeping on a bench outside but doesn't recognise him. He tries waking him up, but then the doctor's like "How can you see me? I'm a ghost." The MC thinks he's delusional or something, so he just leaves. And then the ghost of the doctor starts following him around and then when the doctor sees the MC struggling with homework or some kind of writing work, he easily gives him the answer. The ghost doctor didn't have any memories of his past life or even what his name was and only found out from the article about him that was posted on the MC's phone.

So the ghost doctor starts making the MC study hard and gave him a lot of books to read, and the MC starts being able to answer the very difficult questions and attracts the attention of the smart number one resident at that time. And then they fought and made a bet that whoever got higher marks at the next exam would be granted a wish or something; I don't remember. But at the exam, everyone was struggling and one of the students couldn't take it anymore and tried killing herself by jumping out of the window (I don't remember if it was a girl or guy; it was just really dramatic). Everyone starts running down and panicking and so the ghost doctor's like "call the ambulance and do CPR" so the MC does that and she was saved, I think. And then the top student was really impressed by him and wants to be friends or something.

I don't remember much more, but the ghost doctor's teacher (he was old) was a bit suspicious; he was also interested in the "genius" MC, so like wants him to do a presentation. But then the ghost doctor starts to remember some things, like how he wanted his granddaughter to be with him (she seemed innocent, though), but he had a heart issue and was slowly dying. But like after the accident of the genius doctor, he seemed better than before (I think it was implying that the accident was staged and that he took the heart of the doctor), but he was still suffering.

And that's about all I remember.

Comment: Heh, also some resemblance to the Korean *[Ghost Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Doctor)* series.

Comment: Was the protagonist studying to become a doctor, or something else? Or is he still a high school student?

Comment: Ghost doctor was gud but its not it, the mc was a resident (becoming a doctor after his residency)

Comment: Definitely car crash, definitely ghost? "A true doctor" has a poor-performing resident at a hospital suddenly gain knowledge from a famous doctor, but the doctor was hiking in the woods and died from his injuries while the MC tried to save him. So it's the right premise, but all the details are wrong.

Comment: Honestly maybe it wasnt a car crash that killed him, but I'm sure it was a ghost. I checked out a true doctor, unfortunately it wasn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be ***[Get off of Me](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=156069)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Does a doctor save lives or save souls? When a low-ranking student called Chu Han who had never before has this question, met a ghost, a neurotic self-proclaimed, prodigious doctor, changed his life...

- It's a full colour manhua.
- The protagonist is Chu Han, a dark-haired medical student at the bottom of his class.
- He sees the white-haired ghost of a gifted doctor, Shen Xingzhi, lying on a bench, but doesn't know who he is, and neither does the ghost, since he has amnesia.
- The ghost follows the protagonist home, and discovers his name and the manner of his death (a car accident) on the protagonist's smartphone.
- In a later scene, the protagonist is sitting an exam when a female student decides to leap out of a window, nearly killing herself. The protagonist resuscitates her with CPR.
- The ghost had a mentor, Professor Jiang, who has a heart condition and a young daughter.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like ***[Dr. Duo](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=77808)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Once a brilliant surgeon, Shinonome Keisuke passed away at a young age. He wanders the world as a ghost that only high-school student Kotone Tasuku can see.
> When an accident leaves Tasuku's childhood friend's younger brother severely injured, the only way to save him is Shinonome and Tasuku have to work together to become the most unusual and possibly talented pair of emergency surgeons...

This is a black & white manga, not a coloured manhwa/manhua as you indicated, but the plot details line up very closely to your description. For example, one of the two main characters is the blond-haired ghost of a recently-deceased surgeon, who's invisible to most people. The other is a dark-haired high school student, who first sees him lying on a park bench, and asks if he's okay, thinking he's a regular person. Also, the ghost does help the student with his homework.

[image]

[image]

Comment: idk y its so similar to the manhwa I read before (kinda sus) but I am 100% sure it was colored.

Answer (score 0):

*[The Ghost Doctor](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-ghost-doctor)*

[image: Front cover of The Ghost Doctor]

> Who needs studying when you’ve got the ghost of a 1950’s doctor by your side?!High schooler Mujin escapes the ER with a mystical scalpel, and now he and Aclé, a ghost doctor, are stuck together. With Aclé’s intellect and Mujin’s bravado, the two make the best of their situation, acing exams and saving lives! But their escapades are catching unwanted attention. Everyone from the mafia to esteemed doctors want in on Mujin’s talents, but no one knows Aclé exists! And with Death looming around every corner, how long can they keep up this charade?

Not matching, it's a female doctor, and he meets her in his house after returning from the Emergency Room, not on a bench.

Found with a search for `manhwa surgeon ghost`, which led me to [this Reddit recommendation post](https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/tizchv/medicaldoctor_recommendations/) where the querent mentioned they'd already read "The Ghost Doctor", so I Googled that and saw the details matched.

Comment: Reading a bit more, this is only a surface-level match. But I will leave it up here on the off chance it helps someone else.